# Ubuntu 18.04 install - only wallpaper showing

Tags: system-installation, 18.04

I try installing Ubuntu desktop 18.04 from a DVD. After a while, I see the desktop beaver image appears and nothing else. No mouse, no cursor, no login, no <kbd>ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>alt</kbd>-<kbd>t</kbd> terminal. I am stuck.

- Asus H170M-Plus motherboard,
- New empty Samsung SSD disk,
- Nvidia graphic card.

Comment: go to bios settings, and search for display output, built in display, something like LVDS and disable it.

Comment: Found nothing like LVDS. Found a setting for display output "On board" vs "PCI-E graphics". It was set to Auto, I changed it to PCI-E. No improvement, still unable to install Ubuntu.

Comment: Can you send screenshot of that screen please..

Comment: Sure, what screen ?

Comment: the screen where you look "on board" vs "PCI-E graphics" i have similiar issue with my ASUS H81-T which has Onboard graphics..when  i disable it, everything went fine.

Comment: Is this loading the DVD? It's unclear from the phrase you used "I try installing" whether you are trying it now or you have already done it

Comment: Yes Zanna, this happens when loading the DVD. It makes no difference whether i select "try from DVD" or "install on hard drive". It takes a few minutes to load the DVD content and then the beaver background image appears and the computer freezes.

Comment: PRATAP, I am new to StackExchange. I looked at how to post an image and I dont understand the <ctrl><G> syntax.